# Using background colors in monospaced text

Tags: color, colorbox

I am trying to generate this in my document:

[image: Teletype]

The goal is to have multiple lines that are aligned, which is why I used `\texttt{}`. But using `\colorbox{color}{text}` from the [`xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package, this is what I get (don't mind the different font or color):

[image: Colorbox]

So my questions are:

1. How can I remove the spacing inside the colorboxes?
2. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \texttt{AjuC ER7 (R) (24)
        E
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{VRAAGLNF}
        \color{black}L
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{DVL}
        \color{black}S
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{A}
        \colorbox{gray}{M}
        \colorbox{black}{GM}
        \colorbox{red}{R}
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{P}
        \color{black}DVEPGGVPR
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }\\
    \texttt{AjuE ER9 (R) (24)
        R
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{V}
        \color{black}E
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{AAGLNFRDVL}
        \color{black}VS
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{LG}
        \color{black}G
        \color{white}\colorbox{red}{R}
        \color{black}ID--QS
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{D}
        \color{black}EII
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: To remove the extra space just use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`.

Comment: There is also the `texshade` package, see https://ctan.org/pkg/texshade and https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/texshade-eg.pdf for an example.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - The problem with `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` is that it also removes the vertical space in the box, which I would like to keep.

Comment: @basseur Yes, I noticed it now. I'm doing something :)

Comment: @Marijn - This seems to be just the _perfect_ package for this task! I will look into this. On the other hand, it may be too much effort to really get into it, because I will just have 9 lines of aligned code in my document and probably never have to use it again. ;)

Comment: You might also look at the pgfmolbio package.

Comment: @Ross - While I don't think it helps me with this particular problem, this package appears to be very useful and may come in handy anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @basseur No problem. I just recognized the sequence data so wanted to let you know its available. Texshade is a good solution here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was fun :)

> [image]

You asked two questions, so there are two answers:

The first one is the box. I copied the definition of `xcolor`'s `\colorbox`, modified it, and called it `\tallcbox`. The difference is that the size of the `\colorbox` is the size of its contents plus `\fboxsep` to each side.

I changed `\tallcbox` to have the same width as the contents, and have height and depth equal to the height and depth of a `\strut`.

The second is the "more elegant way of doing this". Elegance is subjective, so I presumed that something along the lines of "less code" and "less" is what you want :)

I defined another command, `\letterbox`, which take the same arguments as `\colorbox` or `\tallcbox`. But `\letterbox` first converts the given color to grayscale using `\colorlet{temp@c}[gray]{#1}`. Then it uses `\extractcolorspec{temp@c}{\color@spec}` to get the properties of this converted color into `\color@spec`. The `\color@spec` for a gray color will be `{gray}{<0--1>}`, where `<0--1>` denotes a number, you guesses, between 0 and 1. Finally, `\letterbox` compares this number with `0.5` and sets the text color to black or white, depending on the value of `<0--1>`.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\black@or@white#1#2{%
  \@tempdima#2 pt
  \ifdim\@tempdima>0.5 pt
    \definecolor{temp@c}{gray}{0}%
  \else
    \definecolor{temp@c}{gray}{1}%
  \fi}
\def\letterbox#1#{\protect\letterb@x{#1}}
\def\letterb@x#1#2#3{%
  \colorlet{temp@c}[gray]{#2}%
  \extractcolorspec{temp@c}{\color@spec}%
  \expandafter\black@or@white\color@spec
  {\color#1{temp@c}\tallcbox#1{#2}{#3}}}
\def\tallcbox#1#{\protect\color@box{#1}}
\def\color@box#1#2{\color@b@x\relax{\color#1{#2}}}
\long\def\color@b@x#1#2#3%
 {\leavevmode
  \setbox\z@\hbox{{\set@color#3}}%
  \ht\z@\ht\strutbox
  \dp\z@\dp\strutbox
  {#1{#2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}\box\z@}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \texttt{AjuC ER7 (R) (24)%
        E%
        \letterbox{black}{VRAAGLNF}%
        L%
        \letterbox{black}{DVL}%
        S%
        \letterbox{black}{A}%
        \letterbox{gray}{M}%
        \letterbox{black}{GM}%
        \letterbox{red}{R}%
        \letterbox{black}{P}%
        DVEPGGVPR%
        \letterbox{black}{LGGECA}%
    }\\
    \texttt{AjuE ER9 (R) (24)%
        R%
        \letterbox{black}{V}%
        E%
        \letterbox{black}{AAGLNFRDVL}%
        VS%
        \letterbox{black}{LG}%
        G%
        \letterbox{red}{R}%
        ID--QS%
        \letterbox{black}{D}%
        EII%
        \letterbox{black}{LGGECA}%
    }
\end{document}
```

---

Ooh, and as the other answer says, you have to protect the end of the lines with `%` to kill the extra spaces.

Comment: +1 for you, very nice solution `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Use comment at end of line `%` and give `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \texttt{AjuC ER7 (R) (24)
        E%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{VRAAGLNF}%
        \color{black}L%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{DVL}%
        \color{black}S%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{A}%
        \colorbox{gray}{M}%
        \colorbox{black}{GM}%
        \colorbox{red}{R}%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{P}%
        \color{black}DVEPGGVPR%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }\\
    \texttt{AjuE ER9 (R) (24)
        R%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{V}%
        \color{black}E%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{AAGLNFRDVL}%
        \color{black}VS%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{LG}%
        \color{black}G%
        \color{white}\colorbox{red}{R}%
        \color{black}ID--QS%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{D}%
        \color{black}EII%
        \color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }
\end{document}
```

Here's the output

[image]

Comment: The problem with `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` is that it also removes the vertical space in the box, which I would like to keep. Is that possible?

Comment: You can add a `\strut` inside the box you want bigger in vertical

Answer (score 4):

I'm almost re-taking the answer by @Mu30 murugans2katgmail and adding the vertical padding with the `strut` trick (here created with an invisible rule):

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\let\oldcolbox\colorbox
\renewcommand\colorbox[2]{%
        \oldcolbox{#1}{\rule[-.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}#2}%
    }%
\begin{document}
    \texttt{AjuC ER7 (R) (24) E\color{white}\colorbox{black}{VRAAGLNF}\color{black}L\color{white}\colorbox{black}{DVL}\color{black}S\color{white}\colorbox{black}{A}\colorbox{gray}{M}\colorbox{black}{GM}\colorbox{red}{R}\color{white}\colorbox{black}{P}\color{black}DVEPGGVPR\color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }\\
    \texttt{AjuE ER9 (R) (24)
        R\color{white}\colorbox{black}{\strut V}\color{black}E\color{white}\colorbox{black}{AAGLNFRDVL}\color{black}VS\color{white}\colorbox{black}{LG}\color{black}G\color{white}\colorbox{red}{R}\color{black}ID--QS\color{white}\colorbox{black}{D}\color{black}EII\color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can control spacing above and below the letter by changing the value of the `\rule`.

EDIT: as suggested if you want exactly the vertical padding to be centered just substitute the `\rule` with a `\strut`:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}


\let\oldcolbox\colorbox
\renewcommand\colorbox[2]{%
        \oldcolbox{#1}{\strut#2}%
    }%
\begin{document}
    \texttt{AjuC ER7 (R) (24) E\color{white}\colorbox{black}{VRAAGLNF}\color{black}L\color{white}\colorbox{black}{DVL}\color{black}S\color{white}\colorbox{black}{A}\colorbox{gray}{M}\colorbox{black}{GM}\colorbox{red}{R}\color{white}\colorbox{black}{P}\color{black}DVEPGGVPR\color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }\\
    \texttt{AjuE ER9 (R) (24)
        R\color{white}\colorbox{black}{\strut V}\color{black}E\color{white}\colorbox{black}{AAGLNFRDVL}\color{black}VS\color{white}\colorbox{black}{LG}\color{black}G\color{white}\colorbox{red}{R}\color{black}ID--QS\color{white}\colorbox{black}{D}\color{black}EII\color{white}\colorbox{black}{LGGECA}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can replace the `\rule[-.5ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}` by a `\strut` and the size will be adjusted exactly.

Comment: yes, indeed, but with rule you can control spacing above and below, anyway to complete it is good to add the "strutted version"

Comment: Sooorry, but I had to pull my "select-as-answer" for the very elegant answer from @PhelypeOleinik ;)

Comment: Don't worry, I see that his answer is much more robust, anyway I proposed my alternative as being more simple and maybe intuitive for dummies, but I guess I would have used the  answer from @PhelypeOleinik too (if I knew it before) ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can have a syntax that allows to align the letters in the source:

1. `!c{...}` denotes a colored block, where `c` is either `b`, `g` or `r`
2. `~` means a “real space”
3. spaces are ignored and can be used for aligning the characters in the source.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{basseur}
 {%
  \makeactives
  \fboxsep=0pt
  \raggedright
  \small\ttfamily
  \sbox0{A}%
  \edef\shortstrut{%
    \vrule height \the\dimexpr 1pt+\ht0\relax
           depth 1pt
           width 0pt
  }%
  \baselineskip=\dimexpr1.05\ht0+\dp0\relax
  \quotation
 }
 {\endquotation}

\newcommand{\makeactives}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`!\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\startcolor
  \catcode`!=\active
  \catcode`~=10
  \catcode` =9
}
\newcommand{\makeactive}[2]{%
}
\newcommand{\startcolor}[2]{%
  \colorbox{#1basseur}{\shortstrut\color{white}#2}%
}

\colorlet{rbasseur}{red}
\colorlet{bbasseur}{black}
\colorlet{gbasseur}{gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{basseur}
AjuC~ER7~(R)~(24)E!b{V R   AAGLNF}L!b{DVL}S!b{A}!g{M}!b{G M}!r{R}!b{P}DVEPG   G VPR!b{LGGECA}\\
AjuE~ER9~(R)~(24)R!b{V}E!b{AAGLNF R   DVL}V   S !b{L    G}G !r{R}   I D--QS!b{D}EII!b{LGGECA}
\end{basseur}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and took [opisthofulax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120984/opisthofulax)' answer and enhanced it in my own way.
I did not want to permanently change the `\fboxsep` for the whole document, so I added two switch commands. Maybe this will help someone in the future!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\oldfboxsep}

\newcommand{\switchfboxZero}{% Stores current \fboxsep and sets it to 0pt
    \setlength{\oldfboxsep}{\fboxsep}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
}
\newcommand{\switchfboxPrevious}{% Restores previous \fboxsep value
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{\oldfboxsep}%
}

\newcommand{\colorWB}[1]{%
    \switchfboxZero%
    \color{white}\colorbox{black}{\strut{#1}}\color{black}%
    \switchfboxPrevious%
}

\newcommand{\colorWG}[1]{%
    \switchfboxZero%
    \color{white}\colorbox{gray}{\strut{#1}}\color{black}%
    \switchfboxPrevious%
}
\newcommand{\colorWR}[1]{%
    \switchfboxZero%
    \color{white}\colorbox{red}{\strut{#1}}\color{black}%
    \switchfboxPrevious%
}
\newcommand{\colorBG}[1]{%
    \switchfboxZero%
    \color{black}\colorbox{green}{\strut{#1}}%
    \switchfboxPrevious%
}

\begin{document}
    \texttt{AjuC ER7 (R) (24) %
        E%
        \colorWB{VRAAGLNF}%
        L%
        \colorWB{DVL}%
        S%
        \colorWB{A}%
        \colorWG{M}%
        \colorWB{GM}%
        \colorWR{R}%
        \colorWB{P}%
        DVEPGGVPR%
        \colorWB{LGGECA}%
    }\\
    \texttt{AjuE ER9 (R) (24) %
        R%
        \colorWB{V}%
        E%
        \colorWB{AAGLNFRDVL}%
        VS%
        \colorWB{LG}%
        G%
        \colorWR{R}%
        ID--QS%
        \colorWB{D}%
        EII%
        \colorWB{LGGECA}%
    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While the OP is asking for a solution in LaTeX I want to present also two solutions how the problem can be solved with ConTeXt.

The first method is to use the `\framed` mechanism where you can use the `backgroundcolor` and `foregroundcolor` keys to change the colors of the text and background.

```
\setupbodyfont[tt]

\defineframed
  [BackgroundColor]
  [frame=off,
   rulethickness=0pt,
   offset=0pt,
   background=color,
   foregroundcolor=white]

\defineframed [BackgroundR] [BackgroundColor] [backgroundcolor=red]
\defineframed [BackgroundK] [BackgroundColor] [backgroundcolor=black]
\defineframed [BackgroundS] [BackgroundColor] [backgroundcolor=gray]

\starttext

AjuC ER7 (R) (24)
E%
\BackgroundK{VRAAGLNF}%
L%
\BackgroundK{DVL}%
S%
\BackgroundK{A}%
\BackgroundS{M}%
\BackgroundK{GM}%
\BackgroundR{R}%
\BackgroundK{P}%
DVEPGGVPR%
\BackgroundK{LGGECA}

AjuE ER9 (R) (24)
R%
\BackgroundK{V}%
E%
\BackgroundK{AAGLNFRDVL}%
VS%
\BackgroundK{LG}%
G%
\BackgroundR{R}%
ID--QS%
\BackgroundK{D}%
EII%
\BackgroundK{LGGECA}

\stoptext
```

[image: Adding background color to text]

Another solution is the use of the `processor` mechanism which is normally used to have more control about the layout of register entries or the formatting of the section counter.

```
\setupbodyfont[tt]

\defineprocessor [BackgroundColor] [color=white]

% \define[2]\BackgroundColorLine
%   {\backgroundline[#1]{\strut#2}}
%
% \defineprocessor [BackgroundR] [BackgroundColor] [command=\BackgroundColorLine  {red}]
% \defineprocessor [BackgroundK] [BackgroundColor] [command=\BackgroundColorLine{black}]
% \defineprocessor [BackgroundS] [BackgroundColor] [command=\BackgroundColorLine {gray}]

\defineprocessor [BackgroundR] [BackgroundColor] [command=\groupedcommand{\backgroundline  [red]\bgroup\begstrut}{\endstrut\egroup}]
\defineprocessor [BackgroundK] [BackgroundColor] [command=\groupedcommand{\backgroundline[black]\bgroup\begstrut}{\endstrut\egroup}]
\defineprocessor [BackgroundS] [BackgroundColor] [command=\groupedcommand{\backgroundline [gray]\bgroup\begstrut}{\endstrut\egroup}]

\starttext

AjuC ER7 (R) (24)
E%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{VRAAGLNF}%
L%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{DVL}%
S%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{A}%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundS}{M}%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{GM}%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundR}{R}%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{P}%
DVEPGGVPR%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{LGGECA}

AjuE ER9 (R) (24)
R%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{V}%
E%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{AAGLNFRDVL}%
VS%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{LG}%
G%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundR}{R}%
ID--QS%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{D}%
EII%
\applyprocessor{BackgroundK}{LGGECA}

\stoptext
```